# Doxygen multiple bold words

Tags: doxygen

I am trying to make an entire line of text bold. The Doxygen documentation states:

> \b  Displays the argument  using a bold font. Equivalent
>   to < b>word< /b>. To put multiple words in bold use < b>multiple
>   words< /b>.

I have tried (before reading HTML commands section):

- \\! \b lots of words \b
- \\! < b> lots of words < /b>
- \\! \b lots of words /b
- \\! \b < lots of words > \b

I looked at HTML tags < B> and < /B> but I don't want to tie the formatting to only HTML output. Aside from this when I tried '\\!< B> lots of words < /B>' it did not work.

Note:

- The text is in paragraph (\par).
- Spaces in < b> and < /b> are added to stop this webpage interpeting them as literal bold tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second attempt is the correct way to bold out multiple words in doxygen (without the spaces between b tags of course). Note that if you are doing non-standard delimiters for comments, then you will need to specify what those delimiers are in your doxygen configuration file.

```
/**
@mainpage
This short example contains some text markup
illustrating how to do html formatting in doxygen.
.
This will be < em>italic< /em> and this is
< b>how you make lots of words bold.< /b> You will
have to remove the spaces from the tags.
*/
```

Comment: I tried < b> bold text < /b> again and it worked. Seems the issue was the opening < b> being attached to the comment marker \\!. Thanks Justin

Comment: @10SecTom glad to hear it!

Comment: The fact that `\\!<` didn't work was is probably due to the fact that the `//!<` is seen as "Putting documentation after members"

Answer (score 8):

Starting with [Doxygen 1.8.0](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/markdown.html), you can also use Markdown syntax ****Bold text****.

```
/**
@mainpage

**This will be rendered as bold text**
*/
```

Comment: This example don't work cause initial * is seen like part of block comment.